# Ionic build IOS app on macincloud - Alternatives to App Store

Tags: android, ios, macos, ionic-framework, mac-in-cloud

I'm a student developer, using Ionic framework and I've developed an app for my friend's company. I have never owned an Apple product.Is there any alternative to paying 100$ for apple developer ID?
I don't need the app to be visible on App Store to anyone. Is it possible, like it is for Android .apk files, to just build the app using xcode on macincloud or local Mac machine and to get that ".apk"-equivelent (.IPA i think?) file so I could share that file with my clients?

I don't own a Mac machine, but let's say I do buy it. Would I still need to own a Apple Dev. ID to build this file and share it with other apple devices?

Comment: If you have clients then surely you can ask money and use that money to pay the yearly fee

Comment: @Zun I will, but before I do that I decided to ask stackoverflow if there's any alternative to that. At least for testing.

Comment: A free developer membership is available but it is quite limited. Adhoc builds are only valid for 7 days and you can only register a single device.  With a paid membership you will get access to TestFlight which is probably a much more practical way of delivering your app for testers

Answer (score 0):

No, you need to pay the $100 fee.